# Where are the models referenced at the ASP.NET web site of SPA tutorial?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

[Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) at the step 5 of the first exercise (*In the Add Existing Item dialog box, navigate to the Source/Assets/Models folder and select all the files. Click Add.*) the tutorial make a reference to a set of files that I don't know where they are. Where I can find those files?

Comment: Where did you install the files to?

Comment: @John at C:\WebCampsTK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the page:

All sample code and snippets are included in the Web Camps Training Kit, available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36393.

Once installed read the readme, you are doing the Hands On Lab (HOL) for AspNetWebApiSpa:

C:\WebCampsTK\HOL\AspNetWebApiSpa\Source\Assets\Models

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I downloaded that file but the problem is that I don't found any *Sources/Assets/Models* path as referred in the tutorial image. Is that image outdated?

Comment: Not sure I've never done that tutorial. Where did the files install to? They do have lots of sample applications on codeplex as well, you might be able to find it there: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/ReadMe.txt

Comment: `C:\WebCampsTK` I searched and that path *Sources/Assets/Models* not exist, so seen to me that the images is outdated.

Comment: @gsc-frank C:\WebCampsTK\HOL\AspNetWebApiSpa\Source\Assets\Models

Comment: Thanks! Definitively the image is outdated, I was looking for *Sources* instead of *Source*.

Comment: @gsc-frank the image does say Source, glad its working for you! :)

Comment: You are right! Silly mistake, I even put in the original question *Source* not *Sources*, but for some reason I searched *Sources* instead of *Source*. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue...

I found the files were installed in:
c:\WebCampsTK\HOL\AspNetWebApiSpa\Source\Ex1-CreatingAWebAPI\End\GeekQuiz\Models

The needed files may be installed elsewhere also (too many folders) but this is where I found them on my system after performing the install.

Hope this helps!